# ¿Qué son los miembros de instancia de una clase?

Tags: java

He encontrado este tecnicismo en varios aportes de stack overflow, sin embargo no alcanzo a percibir el alcance de esta definición.

Quiero imaginar que son exclusivamente los atributos de la clase.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que está bien explicado en el apartado [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) de la documentación de Java.

Para entenderlo hay que referirse necesariamente a la diferencia que hay entre lo que sería una *variable de instancia* y una *variable de clase*.

#### Variable o miembro de instancia

- pertenece solamente a **esa instancia** de la clase. Se usan diferentes ubicaciones de memoria para cada instancia/miembro de la clase.

#### Variable o miembro de clase o estático

- se define usando el modificador `static`
- están asociados con la clase, en lugar de con cualquier objeto. Significa que cada instancia de la clase comparte una variable de clase, que está en una ubicación fija en la memoria.
- cualquier objeto puede cambiar el valor de una variable de clase, pero las variables de clase también se pueden manipular sin crear una instancia de la clase.

---

### Clase de ejemplo

Viendo la clase de ejemplo que ponen en la documentación se entenderá mucho mejor.

Supongamos que desea crear una serie de objetos `Bicycle` y asignarles un número de serie, comenzando con 1 para el primer objeto. Este número de ID es único para cada objeto y, por lo tanto, es una variable de instancia. Al mismo tiempo, necesita un campo para realizar un seguimiento de cuántos objetos de bicicleta se han creado para que sepa qué ID asignar al siguiente. Tal campo no está relacionado con ningún objeto individual, sino con la clase como un todo. Para esto necesita una variable de clase, `numberOfBicycles`, de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Bicycle {
        
    private int cadence;
    private int gear;
    private int speed;
        
    private int id;
    
    private static int numberOfBicycles = 0;

        
    public Bicycle(int startCadence,
                   int startSpeed,
                   int startGear) {
        gear = startGear;
        cadence = startCadence;
        speed = startSpeed;

        id = ++numberOfBicycles;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public static int getNumberOfBicycles() {
        return numberOfBicycles;
    }

    //Métodos getter y setter
}
```

Aquí, las variables de instancia serían `cadence, gear, speed, id`, mientras que `numberOfBicycles` sería una variable de clase.

Vamos a crear varias instancias de la clase:

```
myBici1 = new Bycicle();
myBici2 = new Bycicle();
```

Aquí, `myBici1` y `myBici2` tendrán cada una sos propias variables de instancia, y `myBici1` no podrá ver ni usar ni modificar ninguno de los miembros `cadence, gear, speed, id` de `myBici2` ni viceversa.

En cambio, tanto `myBici1` como `myBici2` podrán ver el valor de `numberOfBicycles` en todo momento, porque es una variable de clase.

De hecho, se podría acceder así, aunque, ojo, esto no es recomendable:

```
myBici1.numberOfBicycles;
myBici2.numberOfBicycles;
```

Se recomienda acceder a las variables de clase usando el propio nombre de la clase, de modo que quede claro que se trata de una variable de clase:

```
Bicycle.numberOfBicycles
```

---

### Métodos

Lo mismo ocurre con los métodos. Si se declara un método `static`, éste pertenecerá a la clase en sí, y se podrá usar incluso sin crear una instancia de la clase.

Por lo general este tipo de métodos se suelen usar para manejar las mismas variables estáticas de la clase.

Por ejemplo, en el caso de la clase anterior:

```
public static int getNumberOfBicycles() {
    return numberOfBicycles;
}
```

No todas las combinaciones de variables y métodos de instancia y clase están permitidas:

- Los métodos de instancia pueden acceder a variables de instancia y métodos de instancia directamente.
- Los métodos de instancia pueden acceder directamente a las variables de clase y los métodos de clase.
- Los métodos de clase pueden acceder directamente a las variables de clase y los métodos de clase.
- Los métodos de clase **no pueden** acceder directamente a variables de instancia o métodos de instancia; deben usar una referencia de objeto. Además, los métodos de clase no pueden usar la palabra clave `this` ya que no hay ninguna instancia a la que hacer referencia.

Answer (score 0):

`Miembros` son tanto atributos como métodos de una clase.

`De Instancia` indica que no son `static`, es decir, están asociados a una instancia/objecto concretos.

Un atributo de instancia puede tener valores distintos en cada instancia (por ejemplo, `array.length`). Un método de instancia puede acceder a los atributos(y a los métodos) de instancia de su instancia/objeto(por ejemplo, `toString()` accede a la información de la instancia/objeto para generar el valor retornado).

Por último, los miembros de instancia no se pueden hacer referencia mediante [NombreDeClase.nombreMiembro] porque eso no especifica la instancia/objeto referida (no puedes hacer `Object.toString()`). Eso sí se puede hacer con miembros estáticos.